# Best way to add search functionality to BlockingQueue

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a structure to use BlockingQueue but also add a functionality to find an element by a property. The requirements are:

1. support all BlockingQueue features, e.g. blocking threads on put and take, preserve insertion order
2. find an element by a property
3. support large dataset (max 100000 items)
4. all methods should handle concurrency
5. the method `find` should not be blocked when queue is being updated in order to provide better search performance. It should behave similar to ConcurrentHashMap where concurrent read is not blocked while being updated in which case it will get last updated value

Here is the solution I came up with. Is there any issue or any better solution?

```
    class Node {
      String Id;
      String Value;
    }


    class Test {
      private final BlockingQueue<Node> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100000);
      private final Map<String, Node> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
      

      public void addNode(Node node) throws QueueFullException {
        if (!queue.offer(node)) {
            throw new QueueFullException();
        }

        map.put(node.id, node);
      }

      public Node takeNode() {
        try {
            Node node = queue.take();
            if (node != null) map.remove(node.id);
            return node;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
      }

      public Node find(String Id) {
        return map.get(Id);
      } 
    }
```

Comment: How is concurrency handled here?

Comment: You'd almost certainly have a better time with correct concurrent behavior just having a normal queue behind a lock.

Comment: I think @LouisWasserman is on the mark with his suggestion.  I was going to suggest implementing your own `BlockingQueue` (using the [ArrayBlockingQueue source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/64cc2bc73816f3e0a91776805482fee37fa37bbe/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java) as reference and using a `Map` instead of `Object[]`) but think Louis' suggestion is far superior.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I just added a new requirement #5. I have thought about modifying the ArrayBlockingQueue, but in order to support find by id, i would need to use a map. But I don't want to map to be behind the same lock. I figured eventually I will have to use ConcurrentHashMap aside from the BlockingQueue

Comment: Maybe I missed something but you could just use `queue.stream().filter(node -> node.id.equals(id)).findFirst().orElseGet(Node::new);` to find your desired value (or a default constructed one if the node does not exist), i.e. no need for a map.

Comment: @Sebphil you need to filter then find first.

Comment: @Sebphil as requirement #3 states, it should handle large dataset, there could be 100000 items, so I don't want to loop through the queue everytime I search

Comment: @matt yeah, you are right thanks!

Comment: There are the obvious race condition, where the node has been taken from the queue, but hasn't been removed from the map. During that brief interlude something could get the node from the map. Or where the node has been added to the queue, but not put in the map yet.

Comment: @matt this is a good point. I guess it might be fine to have the map and queue to have a brief inconsistency since the map is just for search, kinda a cache layer. Any suggestion how this can be improved?